# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appoauth2_provider'

Tags: python, django, facebook

I followed all the directions in importing Facebook into my python django app. However, when  I try to migrate , I get an error "No module named'appoauth2_provider'
I am using Windows 10, Python 3.6.0.

```
(app) C:\Users\Corey Shaw\Desktop\goodrvirtualenv\app\Scripts\app>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\COREYS~1\Desktop\GOODRV~1\app\lib\site-packages\django-1.10-py3.6.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\COREYS~1\Desktop\GOODRV~1\app\lib\site-packages\django-1.10-py3.6.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\COREYS~1\Desktop\GOODRV~1\app\lib\site-packages\django-1.10-py3.6.egg\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\COREYS~1\Desktop\GOODRV~1\app\lib\site-packages\django-1.10-py3.6.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\COREYS~1\Desktop\GOODRV~1\app\lib\site-packages\django-1.10-py3.6.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\COREYS~1\Desktop\GOODRV~1\app\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appoauth2_provider'
```

Comment: try `pip install oauth2_provider`

Comment: Didnt work :( . It is actually "appoauth2_provider"(my app name)

Comment: Does your `appoauth2_provider` directory have a `__init__.py` file in it?

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you resolve this?